# How to import sqlite3 in pycharm?

Tags: sqlite, pycharm

How can I use sqlite3 in pycharm?

I found out that sqlite3 is basically included in standard library. However, when I try to import it, the module is not found.

import sqlite3 << this returns a import error.

Is sqlite3 module name different in pycharm?

Comment: PyCharm uses the interpreter configured in Settings | Project ... | Project Interpreter, it doesn't apply any changes to it. Make sure sqlite3 is available for the selected interpreter. Perhaps Python was built without the library.

Answer (score 1):

Putting answer for anyone who lands on this page searching for a solution for Windows OS:

For me the issue was with DLL file of sqlite3.
Solution:

1. I took DLL file from [sqlite site](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html). This might vary based on your
   version of python installation.
2. I pasted it in the DLL directory of
   the env. for me it was "C:\Anaconda\Lib", but check for yours.
   [image: Before and After placing DLL file]